# Is there any difference in meaning between "ill-treat" and "mistreat"?

Tags: meaning, verbs

I'm aware they are synonyms, but all the same I'm interested in knowing if one word is usually used more in one particular context, for example, or reserved for such a context. Or whether either one of the verbs connotes a stronger action than the other. Any information/comments would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

illtreat means treating **badly**, but mistreat means treating **wrongly**.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELU!  I think you're on to something here; could you develop the difference between those two words, maybe include some additional context or example sentences highlighting the differences?  This would greatly help the OP in answering the question.  Thanks!

Comment: This answer seems perfectly clear to me.

Answer (score 1):

In simple terms:

***maltreat* = *ill-treat***

*maltreat* is **rougher** than *mistreat*

Need a proof?:-)

Read the entry on "abuse" (as a verb) in:

> [Garner's Dictionary of Legal Usage](https://books.google.ca/books?id=YwLiALrHLCEC&pg=PA10#v=onepage&q&f=false)  - Page 10 Bryan A. Garner
>
> **abuse,** vb.; misuse; mistreat; ill-treat; maltreat. These verbs share the sense “to deal with in a harmful or wrongful way.”

[Edit]
One of Garner's references is mentioned on that page as supporting the view that "*maltreat* is usu. restricted to the **rougher** forms of *mistreating*."

Comment: Your source does not back up your claim that maltreat is rougher than mistrreat.

Comment: @StevenLittman I've updated the answer to clarify this aspect. Please have a look at that page.

Answer (score 1):

The migrant workers during Covid 19 were mistreated by the state governments by not giving them food and shelter.
The ill-treatment on the animals will invite heavy panalties or even jail.
Mistreatment means behave wrongly.
ill- treatment means behave cruelly.

Comment: Welcome to the site Ravindra, your answer, whilst informative would benefit from a link to anauthoritative source for the claim of the relative meanings. Partake of our [tour] and when you have not a little spare-time, enjoy the [help] for what it can tell you about our ways.